# Why is there difference between OpenCV's camera grabbing and Windows default Camera app with same resolution?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, resolution

Got a webcam attached to a robot, static.
Windows 11 Camera app at 3840x2880 resolution gives this:
[image]

and OpenCV gives this (code snippet to follow):
[image: OpenCV]

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3840)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 2880)
_, image = camera.read()
height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]
cv2.line(image, (int(width/2), 0), (int(width/2), height), (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.line(image, (0, int(height/2)), (width, int(height/2)), (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

No camera calibration done (yet).

Ignore the color differences please.
It's obvious they are seeing different FOVs and have the center in different places.
What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: there are some steps between the camera sensor and a RGB image in the computer RAM. Without knowing the camera and the interface it isnt clear which steps are performed on the camera, which steps are performed by the driver and which steps are performed in the capturing library and which steps are performed in the viewer application. It could be possible, that the windows camera app parametrizes the camera or postprocesses the image itself. My guess is, that the camera application performs a white balancing and contrast enhancement. Find minimum/maximum R and G and B and stretch it to 0..255

Comment: don't trust the windows camera. its crop of the larger area (that you see when reading with OpenCV) isn't even symmetric. watch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKoJD.jpg

Comment: @Gabe sorry, didnt recognize that the image field of view is a bit different. So that's definitely not just a contrast enhancement + white balancing, but still it could be a post processing by the windows camera app, or a parametrizationof the camera by that app. Can you also try VLC media player, to get a third opinion?

Answer (score 2):

Some camera's have dual optional streams like yours, with these you can configure different types of resolutions and fps according to hardware specs. `VideoCaptureProperties` [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) says

> Reading / writing properties involves many layers. Some unexpected
> result might happens along this chain. Effective behaviour depends
> from device hardware, driver and API Backend.

OpenCV backend doesn't support all of the camera apis in industry. If you are lucky and they match, you can be able to use OpenCV capture properties.

**What else you can do:**

1. You can use camera SDK if it is available then you can configure.
2. You can try different index alternatives for `VideoCapture()` like
   `VideoCapture(-1)`, `VideoCapture(0)`, `VideoCapture(2)` ... Maybe one of them matches with the desired channel stream.